# Selecting certain region based on BB coordinates in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, bounding-box, qlabel

I have created a simple GUI in Pyqt to upload a CSV file containing image path and bounding box coordinates values with a push button. And it has another push button which goes to the next image. And the label area to display an image with the bounding box around an object in it as shown below.

Now I would like to assign some name to the object with the bounding box. For this purpose I have another push button. But when there are more than one objects in an image I would like to click on one of the bounding box and then assign the same. But I am struggling to make this bounding box area clickable.

I have seen examples of getting the pixel value or (x, y) when clicked on image but this one seems to be difficult for me.

And code for the same is below.

[image]

And the code for the same is as below.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import csv
from pygui import Ui_MainWindow
from collections import namedtuple
import sys
import cv2

Row = namedtuple('Row', ('image_path', 'x', 'y', 'w', 'h'))

class mainProgram(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(mainProgram, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.data=None

    def all_callbacks(self):
        # Open directory callback
        self.Upload.clicked.connect(self.on_click_upload)
        # Next button callback
        self.Next.clicked.connect(self.on_click_next)

    def convert_cv_image_to_qt(self, cv_img):
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        return QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(convert_to_Qt_format)

    def draw_bb_on_image(self, image_data, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=2):
        self.image_path = image_data.image_path
        self.x, self.y = int(image_data.x), int(image_data.y)
        self.w, self.h = int(image_data.w), int(image_data.h)
        image = cv2.imread(self.image_path)
        output_img = cv2.rectangle(image, (self.x, self.y), (self.x+self.w, self.y+self.h), color, thickness)
        qimage = self.convert_cv_image_to_qt(output_img)
        return qimage

    def on_click_upload(self):

        dialog = QFileDialog()
        csv_file = dialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Import CSV", "", "CSV data files (*.csv)")

        try:
            with open(csv_file[0]) as fp:
                reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
                data = [Row(*r) for r in reader]

        except PermissionError:
            print("You don't seem to have the rights to open the file")

        if 0 == len(data):
            print("File is empty, select another file")
            return

        self.count = 0
        self.data = data
        upload_image = self.draw_bb_on_image(data[0])
        self.label.setPixmap(upload_image)
        self.label.show()

    def next_image(self, offset=1):
        if self.data is None:
            return
        self.count = (self.count + offset) % len(self.data)
        next_image = self.draw_bb_on_image(self.data[self.count])
        self.label.setPixmap(next_image)
        self.label.show()

    def on_click_next(self):
        self.next_image(offset=1)

    def on_click_previous(self):
        self.next_image(offset=-1)


def execute_pipeline():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    annotationGui = mainProgram()
    annotationGui.show()
    annotationGui.all_callbacks()

    # Exit the window
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_pipeline()
```

I want to assign a name to the object. For this I would like to make this bounding box area clickable.

Comment: How are you showing the image? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Sorry for the delayed update. Question is updated with MRE.

Comment: @iamkk Your question is confusing: 1) You say that an image has several bounding boxes but a .csv only allows you to have 1 bounding box, how do you get the other bounding boxes? Could you show a sample of the .csv? 2) Your requirement is confusing, from what I understand is to load a .csv, show one of the rows, click on the BB, a dialog opens where the user sets the name, and then when the application is closed the information (filename, bb and name) in a .csv, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry for the confusion. 1) Let's consider it for one bb. If I am able to do it for one bb then I can modify accordingly for many. Therefore .csv contains just one bb for now. 2) Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to make some modifications to the requirement since the description does not match the implementation. Since there are several bounding boxes so the .csv format will limit it so I will use a .json.

Instead of using QLabel it is better to use QGraphicsPixmapItem since it allows obtaining the click position, to draw the bounding box I use QGraphicsRectItem.

Considering the above, the json must have the following structure:

```json
[
    {
        "filename": "/path/of/filename1.png",
        "boxes": [
            {
                "width": 100,
                "x": 10,
                "y": 10,
                "name": "foo",
                "height": 100
            },
            {
                "width": 100,
                "x": 110,
                "y": 110,
                "name": "bar",
                "height": 100
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "filename": "/path/of/filename2.png",
        "boxes": [
            {
                "width": 800,
                "x": 30,
                "y": 50,
                "name": "baz",
                "height": 200
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

```py
from functools import cached_property
import json
import random
from typing import List

from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QPainter, QPalette, QPen, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QFileDialog,
    QGraphicsPixmapItem,
    QGraphicsRectItem,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGridLayout,
    QInputDialog,
    QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)

KEY_INDEX = 0


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Box:
    x: int
    y: int
    width: int
    height: int
    name: str = ""

    def to_rect(self):
        return QRectF(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class ImageItem:
    filename: str
    boxes: List[Box]


def load_items(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as fp:
        return ImageItem.schema().loads(fp.read(), many=True)


def save_items(items, filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as fp:
        fp.write(ImageItem.schema().dumps(items, many=True))


class BoxItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, parent_item):
        super().__init__(parent_item)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 100))
        super().hoverEnterEvent(event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.NoBrush))
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(event)


class ImageViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._image_items = list()
        self._current_index = -1

        self.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)

        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)

        self._pixmap_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        scene.addItem(self._pixmap_item)

    @property
    def image_items(self):
        return self._image_items

    @image_items.setter
    def image_items(self, items):
        self._image_items.clear()
        self._current_index = -1
        self._image_items.extend(items)
        if items:
            self._current_index = 0
        self._load_image_item()

    @property
    def current_image_item(self):
        if 0 <= self._current_index < len(self.image_items):
            return self.image_items[self._current_index]

    @property
    def current_index(self):
        return self._current_index

    def previous_item(self):
        self._current_index = max(self._current_index - 1, 0)
        self._load_image_item()

    def next_item(self):
        self._current_index = min(self._current_index + 1, len(self.image_items) - 1)
        self._load_image_item()

    def _fit_to_window(self):
        self.setSceneRect(self.scene().itemsBoundingRect())
        self.fitInView(self.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def _load_image_item(self):
        image_item = self.current_image_item
        if image_item:
            for child_item in self._pixmap_item.childItems():
                if isinstance(child_item, BoxItem):
                    child_item.setParentItem(None)
            self._pixmap_item.setPixmap(QPixmap(image_item.filename))
            for i, box in enumerate(image_item.boxes):
                rect_item = BoxItem(self._pixmap_item)
                rect_item.setRect(box.to_rect())
                rect_item.setPen(QPen(QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)), 5))
                rect_item.setData(KEY_INDEX, i)
        else:
            for child_item in self._pixmap_item.childItems():
                if isinstance(child_item, BoxItem):
                    child_item.setParentItem(None)
            self._pixmap_item.setPixmap(QPixmap())
        self._fit_to_window()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        sp = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        items = self.scene().items(sp)
        if not items:
            return
        item = items[0]
        if not isinstance(item, BoxItem):
            return
        i = item.data(KEY_INDEX)
        box_item = self.current_image_item.boxes[i]
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(
            self,
            self.tr("Change name"),
            self.tr("Name:"),
            QLineEdit.Normal,
            box_item.name,
        )
        if ok:
            box_item.name = text

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self._fit_to_window()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        container = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        layout = QGridLayout(container)
        layout.addWidget(self.load_button, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.previous_button, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.next_button, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.viewer, 2, 0, 1, 2)

        self.previous_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.next_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.load_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_load_button_clicked)
        self.previous_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_previous_button_clicked)
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_next_button_clicked)

    @cached_property
    def load_button(self):
        return QPushButton("Load")

    @cached_property
    def previous_button(self):
        return QPushButton("Previous")

    @cached_property
    def next_button(self):
        return QPushButton("Next")

    @cached_property
    def viewer(self):
        return ImageViewer()

    def handle_load_button_clicked(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, "Import JSON", "", "JSON data files (*.json)"
        )
        if filename:
            self.viewer.image_items = load_items(filename)
        self._update_buttons()

    def handle_previous_button_clicked(self):
        self.viewer.previous_item()
        self._update_buttons()

    def handle_next_button_clicked(self):
        self.viewer.next_item()
        self._update_buttons()

    def _update_buttons(self):
        self.previous_button.setEnabled(self.viewer.current_index > 0)
        self.next_button.setEnabled(
            self.viewer.current_index < (len(self.viewer.image_items) - 1)
        )

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super().closeEvent(event)
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            None, "Import JSON", "", "JSON data files (*.json)"
        )
        if filename:
            save_items(self.viewer.image_items, filename)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = MainWindow()
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    ret = app.exec()
    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. This exactly was my requirement but I had different approach. However, the BB's from previous images are carried over onto the next image. For example, if I have one BB per image(total 3 images), when I view the last image it will display three BBs (including the previous two). Could you please help me with this? I suppose I need to change in _load_image_item function, but I am not sure though. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand the code correctly problem is not with the update. I can update the file correctly but when an image is displayed BBs of previous images are also displayed. And I tried to debug _load_image_item (as this is responsible to  display BBs), but I could not succeed with that. Is this understanding correct or am I going in a wrong direction to fix the problem?

Comment: @iamkk I already solved that problem, have you tested my updated code?

Comment: does this script only accepts the input in the format it is given in the example .json file? I mean in this order [width, x, y, name, height]. Because the file is not loaded when I alter this order. I was trying to have an order as it is in `class Box`. I don't quite understand what is with this order. I tried loading it with `OrderedDict` and save with `sort_keys=True` as it is saving in random order too.